# Хочу сделать свой блокнот для заметок на python, но не могу сделать проверку имени от пользователя (checkName)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#my notes

name = "Fraus"
password = "89834189145"

checkName()

def checkName():   
    name1 = input("Select password: ");
    
    if name1 == name:
        checkPassword()
    else:
         print("Wrong")

def checkPassword():
    password1 = input("Select password: ");

    if password1 == password:
        greeting()
    else:
        print("Wrong")

def greeting():
    print("Здравствуйте Данил")
```

Ошибка:

```
name 'checkName' is not defined
```

Comment: В чем вопрос, что не так?

Comment: В Visual studio checkName() Дается с ошибкой "name 'checkName' is not defined", в интернете об этом искал, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: переместите checkName() в конец

Comment: функция вызывается, раньше чем объявлена, решение - совет выше

Comment: Я конечно пробовал, но идет метод checkPassword, a не checkName

Comment: Хорошо, с частью проблемы я разобрался, у меня везде написано было select password, но теперь он не происходит метод checkPassword(), checkName я поставил в конец

Comment: не описание функции def checkName(), а ее вызов checkName() - в конец ;)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Функцию `def checkName()` сначала нужно объявить: "преждевременный" вызов `checkName()` - причина вашего `NameError: name 'checkName' is not defined`

Попробуйте так:

```
name = "Fraus"
password = "89834189145"


def checkName():   
    guess = input("Input name: ");
    
    if guess == name:
        checkPassword()
    else:
         print("Wrong name")


def checkPassword():
    guess = input("Input password: ");

    if guess == password:
        greeting()
    else:
        print("Wrong password")


def greeting():
    print("Hello Fraus!")


checkName()
```

Comment: А пояснить в чём суть? Хотя бы из камментов скопировать, если прямо лень писать. Голый код не привествуется.

Comment: @CrazyElf не то, чтобы лень, но когда нужно пояснить такие очевидные вещи, слова нахожу с трудом... проще код показать

Comment: "Нужно себя заставлять" ))  Потом проще будет, поверьте. Главное практиковаться.

Comment: @CrazyElf первый ответ без пояснений за три месяца и так попасть "на ковер"... стыдоба ))

Comment: Да я только с виду строгий, не серчайте ))